# tf.segment_max error: segment ids are not increasing by 1

Tags: tensorflow

`tf.segment_max()` and other segment ops generally [require the segment IDs to be consecutive](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/math_ops.html#segmentation). When applying this op to dynamically produced batches and using `tf.unique()` to define segments, the segment IDs may not be consecutive, producing an error. The two cases (error / no error) are illustrated below:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    data = tf.constant([[1, 3, 5], [6, 2, 7], [9, 9, 2], [9, 5, 1]])
    #labels = ['a','r','r','d'] # this works
    labels = ['a','r','d','r']  # error: segment ids are not increasing by 1
    y, idx = tf.unique(labels) 
    maxs = tf.segment_max(data, idx)
    rval = sess.run([idx, maxs])
    print('indices: ', rval[0])
    print('maxs: ', rval[1])
```

How can the general case of non-consecutive segment IDs be handled?

Answer (score 2):

Considering the question was posted quite a while ago, I am not sure whether the **OP** has already found the answer. However, I am posting the solution for anyone who might end up with the same problem.

The trick, here, is to use `tf.math.unsorted_segment_max()`.It is pretty simple. For example, consider the following code-

```
# Data
data = tf.constant([0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.7, 0.1], dtype=tf.float32)
# Unique segements with Segment IDs
unique_elems, segment_ids = tf.unique(tf.constant([1, 2, 1, 1, 2], dtype=tf.int32))
# Count the number of unique segments.
nb_segments = tf.size(tf.unique(segment_ids)[0])
# Result
result = tf.math.unsorted_segment_max(
    data=data, segment_ids=segment_ids, num_segments=nb_segments
)
tf.print(result) 
# result turns out to be [0.7, 0.5]
```

In the above code, we are first finding the indices with the same values using the `tf.unique()` method. Then, we use the `tf.unsorted_segment_max()` method to find the maximum values in the `data` tensor corresponding to those segments of indices.

You can read more about it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/unsorted_segment_max).